# What can the reals of an inner model be?

Tags: logic, set-theory, terminology, descriptive-set-theory

This is probably a silly question. Call a set of reals $X$ a *constructibility ideal* (in analogy with a *Turing ideal*) if $X$ is closed under effective join $r\oplus s: n\mapsto 2^{r(n)}3^{s(n)}$ and relative constructibility. Clearly, if $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is such that $L(X)\cap\mathbb{R}=X$, then $X$ is a constructibility ideal. My question is: does the converse hold?

I don't see that it does. For example, let $X_n$ be the set of reals which are (lightface) $\Pi^1_n$, and $X$ the set of (lightface) projective reals $X=\bigcup X_n$ - all computed in $V$, of course. Then the projective theory of $\omega$ will be in $L(X)\setminus X$, but if $V$ has enough large cardinals then I think $X$ is a constructibility ideal.

If not, what do we call a set of reals $X$ such that $L(X)\cap\mathbb{R}=X$?

Comment: I don't know the answer, or if there is an established term. But I'd consider calling such $X$ along the lines of "constructibly saturated".

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was leaning towards "mousey" myself. :P

Comment: If you want to go there, a group of mice is called "Mischief". :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm writing a children's book on fine structure and iteration trees - it's called "If you give a mouse a measure." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_You_Give_a_Mouse_a_Cookie)

Comment: If you give a mouse a measure, it becomes a terrible mouse.

Comment: Let $C_{2n+2}$ be the largest countable $\Sigma^1_{2n+2}$ set of reals, then $L(C_{2n+2})\cap \mathbb{R}=C_{2n+2}$. Let $Q_{2n+1}$ be the largest countable $\Pi^1_{2n+1}$ set of reals then $L(Q_{2n+1})\cap \mathbb{R}=Q_{2n+1}$. However if you take $C_{2n+1}$ then we must have $L(C_{2n+1})=L(C_{2n+2})$, so the above equality must fail for the $C_{2n+1}$ sets. So I guess you would call such sets the largest thin $\Pi^1_{2n+1}$ sets of reals for every $n$...

Comment: ... as an aside $C_{2n+2}$ is exactly the set of reals of $\mathcal{M_{2n}}$ (the minimal mouse with $2n$ Woodins and $Q_{2n+3}$ are exactly the reals of $M_{2n+1}$ (result of Steel)

Comment: @CarloVonSchnitzel What if $X$ does not consist only of projective sets? (Or even, is uncountable?) I'm really interested in **all* $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $L(X)\cap\mathbb{R}=X$.

Comment: The same thing holds in general, considering any appropriate pointclass of the Wadge hierarchy, at least under $\text{AD}^+$.

Comment: It looks like Rachid answered this question. Given any real $a$, do we get a counterexample by considering the reals constructible from any of $a$, $a^{\#}$, $a^{\#\#}$, etc.?